# transfer Bitcoin without synchronizing Bitcoin core

Tags: transactions

I installed Bitcoin core recently but its not synchronizing right now. I sent one address from file menu like this below to one of my friend and he is send me some Bitcoin:

```
13BuBwcQM2WwedYzqkccovjYYPKBAc6RWE
```

The problem is that I haven't enough storage in my PC to download all of the data so I can't synchronize my bit-coin core and it shows 0.00 balance. I have another Bitcoin wallet in https://blockchain.info site

How I can send my Bitcoin to my new wallet?

If I uninstalled my Bitcoin core wallet, will my bit coin be lost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good (or bad) news is that [your friends hasn't sent you any bitcoins to address `13BuBwcQM2WwedYzqkccovjYYPKBAc6RWE` yet](https://www.blocktrail.com/BTC/address/13BuBwcQM2WwedYzqkccovjYYPKBAc6RWE) so ask him not to do so until you configure your account to blockchain.info or another online wallet.

Before you proceed with deleting your local wallet, keep the `wallet.dat` file so you will be able to restore it later on if needed.

Comment: so you mean that before synch Bitcoin core the address is not valid and no body can not sent bitcoin. am i right?

Comment: @Mohammad no, the address is valid, it just hasn't received any funds because most probably nobody has sent funds to it.

Comment: thanks but actually there was two address and i check it at https://www.blocktrail.com/ my it has 0.095 bitcoin at it has money that my friend sent so what should i do right now i have a valid address with 0.095 bit coin and my pc wallet is not synch. how i can send it to one online wallet that i have,whiteout synch my pc wallet

Comment: @Mohammad OK so that's another address I guess. Go to your RPC console and type in: `listreceivedbyaddress 0 false`, then unlock your wallet if locked and run the command: `dumpprivkey ADDRESS`, where `ADDRESS` is the address you'll get from the previous command. Then import this private key to blockchain.info and you're good to go.

Comment: thanks ,i m new in it,can you please help me how i can access to my RPC console

Comment: @Mohammad See [How do I open my RPC console?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/36712/how-do-i-open-my-rpc-console)