# How do I open my RPC console?

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc

Someone just asked me to open the RPC console, as part of debugging something else. How do I do that?

I'm using Bitcoin-Qt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click Help > Debug window, then click on the Console tab.